# Why is writing to a tun interface so slow?

Tags: c, linux, tun

I've added instrumentation to my code:

```
state.worker_stats.counters[TUN_TX]++;
state_switch_activity(KERN_WRITE_TUN);
ssize_t wrote = write(peer->tun_fd, plaintext, plaintext_len);
state_switch_activity(USER_UDP_TO_TUN);
```

where:

```
static uint64_t nanonow() {
    struct timespec t;
    int err = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t);
    if (err) {
        perror(__FILE__);
        exit(errno);
    }
    return t.tv_nsec + 1000000000 * t.tv_sec;
}

enum state_activity state_switch_activity(enum state_activity new_activity) {
    uint64_t now = nanonow();
    struct state_worker_stats *ws = &state.worker_stats; // abbreviate "state.worker_stats."

    enum state_activity old_activity = ws->current_activity;
    ws->current_activity = new_activity;
    uint64_t duration = now - ws->last_change;
    ws->last_change = now;
    ws->times[old_activity] += duration;

    return old_activity;
}
```

This, and other instrumentation, results in per-packet stats:

```
  outbound:
      KERN_READ_TUN per TUN_RX:      3.199167 µs
    USER_TUN_TO_UDP per TUN_RX:      4.038177 µs
       USER_ENCRYPT per UDP_TX_UNIQ: 7.955924 µs
      KERN_SEND_UDP per UDP_TX:      15.789421 µs
    USER_TX_HISTORY per UDP_TX_UNIQ: 0.603579 µs

  incoming:
      KERN_RECV_UDP per UDP_RX:      6.712680 µs
    USER_UDP_TO_TUN per UDP_RX:      5.095780 µs
    USER_RX_HISTORY per UDP_RX:      1.087274 µs
       USER_DECRYPT per UDP_RX_UNIQ: 11.485002 µs
     KERN_WRITE_TUN per TUN_TX:      20.241663 µs
```

(I've sanity checked my userspace and kernel/system totals against the results from `getrusage()` and they very nearly agree, so I'm confident in my instrumentation.)

The biggest use of time, for incoming packets, is writing them to tun0 (20.241663 µs per packet).

Sending UDPs is also very slow.

- What can I do to increase the speed of write() and sendmsg()?  (25µs of system time, per 1500 byte packet, limits me to 480Mbps if my userspace code uses no CPU time.)
- Are 1Gbps+ tunnels possible in userspace on Linux?
- If so, how?

Comment: Are you sure your measurement method gives relevant result for throughput? Single iteration of `write()` 1480 bytes to TUN interface measured with `clock_gettime()` indeed takes ≈10..30 μs on my system, but 1000000 iterations of the same `write()` in a loop takes about 700..800 ns per iteration.

Comment: @dimich Thanks for your comment.  The measured times are averaged over thousands of packets.  Each worker has to receive a UDP packet, decrypt it and write it to the tun interface.  i.e. Writing to tun is done many times, but not in a tight loop.  Perhaps batching writes would help throughput, at the cost of latency?  Could you post your fast (7-800ns) code in case I've overlooked something obvious?

Comment: Don't you use multiqueue interface (`IFF_MULTI_QUEUE`), do you? My test code is here: [https://0x0.st/Hv9a.c](https://0x0.st/Hv9a.c).

Comment: @dimich Yes, I'm using `IFF_MULTI_QUEUE` to give each worker its own file descriptor/queue for the tunnel.

Comment: @dimich Thanks, I can confirm that your code takes 2µs per packet sent on my desktop PC, 10x faster than my writes.  I will try batching my tun `write()`s.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.